# ViewHolder ImageView Android

Tags: java, android

I've designed a Chord object that is made of two Strings and an ImageView.

```
public class Accordo {
private String nome, note;
private ImageView imagine;

// all the get and set methods
}
```

when I want to refer to it in my custom ViewHolder, more specifically when I `@override` the `onBindViewHolder()` method, I write:

```
holder.nome.setText(chord.getNome());
holder.note.setText(chord.getNote());
```

for TextViews I can use the `setText()` method. But what is the equivalent for `ImageViews`?

**EDIT**
I could use `setImageResource()` but it takes an int from a drawable.

Since I need a recyclerView with a different Image for every row, I need something that I can setup later in another class and have something like:

```
private void prepareMovieData() {
        Movie movie = new Movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "**LocallyStoredImage**");
        movieList.add(movie);
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this approach:

- First, inside the class (Activity or Fragment) that shows the RecyclerView items, define a primitive array of drawables like this:

  ```
  private int[] menuIcons = {
      R.drawable.user,
      R.drawable.customer,
      R.drawable.list,
      R.drawable.leads
  };
  ```
- Also create an instance of your Adapter here for later;

  ```
  private SampleRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
  ```

Still from your Activity or Fragment, initialize your values

```
private void initRecyclerViewData(){

   List<SampleData> data = new ArrayList<>();

   data.add(new DataObject("Title of row 1", menuIcons[0]));
   data.add(new DataObject("Title of row 2", menuIcons[1]));
   data.add(new DataObject("Title of row 3", menuIcons[2]));
   data.add(new DataObject("Title of row 4", menuIcons[3]));

   //now initialize your adapter - we will create the adapter next
   mAdapter = new SampleRecyclerAdapter(data);
   mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now that we have initialized our adapter, let us see how we can show the images inside the adapter - when the view is bound;

```
//inside your Adapter class;

....

private List<DataObject> mMenuItemObjects;

public SampleRecyclerAdapter(List<DataObject> menuItemObjects) {
    mMenuItemObjects = menuItemObjects;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainMenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemName.setText(mMenuItemObjects.get(position).getName());

    holder.itemIcon.setImageResource(mMenuItemObjects.get(position).getIcon());
}
```

That code above means that you have an `ArrayList` of type DataObject. Remember, when we instantiated our adapter in the activity, we passed an array of data each of which had a title and an icon (drawable).

That is the easiest way to set your image on the recyclerviewer inside onBindViewHolder method.

NOTE: You must create a ViewHolder class and DataObject (latter is a plain old java object).

Good luck and I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! how much would it cost in terms of performance and space having 84 Images like this?

Comment: I would definitely consider moving those images to some server somewhere then use Picasso library to automatically set them. Have all those images in your drawable folders  and considering their sizes, you could be looking at a serious speed impact!

Comment: ok maybe I'll try it out the way you described in your answer and then if there are problems I'll consider moving them to a server

Comment: Absolutely. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Should I add the Image array in my Accordo class?

Comment: Add the images array inside the activity that holds the RecyclerView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115661/discussion-between-daniele-and-eenvincible).

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of image will be setImageResource().

```
holder.imagine.setImageResource(chord.getImage());
```

Comment: doesn't `setImageResource()` take an int? I've defined an ImageView

Comment: Yes it takes an int. holder.imagine.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

Comment: If you want to use url then use, holder.imagine.setImageURI(Uri.parse("image path"));

Comment: Since I need a recyclerView with a different Image for every row, I need something that I can setup later in another class

Comment: I hope you are already doing this: you pass back an array of images to the adapter from your activity or fragment. then based on the position, you can set the value of the imageView

Comment: @Eenvincible no, I have not defined any Image Array how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a class which would hold your titles and images
2. Make a ArrayList of that particular class.
3. Add Data to the Arraylist
4. Call `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` after your `list.add(...)`
5. use something like `Picasso` in your `onBindViewHolder()` to load images(guessing that the images come from some kind of database in URI Form)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the Images are locally stored they are in my drawable folder.

Comment: Well in that case, if the images are less than 10 , you can do something like, pass the name of the image Eg. if there are 3 images, save delete and edit. You can pass a String called imageName(name of the image something like "edit" or "save") and run a switch inside your  `onBindViewHolder()` and Eg. if `case "edit" : setImageResource(R.drawable.edit);`

Comment: Woah! 84 Images in your Drawable Folder? thats gonna make your Apk file size HUGE, mate. Instead i would suggest storing them on a platform like `Cloudinary` and fetching them from the there using `Picasso`.

Comment: This is really my first app so I don't know how much it would increase the app size. Even because my Idea was to make this app completely offline. Can you give me an idea of how much space it would take? They Images are around 13KB

Comment: If its 13KB then it won't take much, it would be around 8-10mb or less. but if your apps is offline, you would have to make a int array holding all the images, then in your `onBindViewHolder()` call like `array[postion]` in your setImageResource